Download From WebView
i have an website that has users. Credentials read from an sql database each user sees his folder with his vat i have a folder structure and i want could download files from there from browser works perfect but from webview not. After a lot attempts i make it to start the download in the download manager but stops immediately. trys again but nothing here is how folder structure works and how download url works in app.js
// Route to get the folder structure
app.get('/get-folder-structure', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.session.vat) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
    }

    const vat = req.session.vat.toString();
    const folderPath = path.join('D:', vat);

    try {
        const folderStructure = await getFolderStructure(folderPath);
        res.json(folderStructure);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading folder structure:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

// Route to download a file
app.get('/download/:filePath', (req, res) => {
    // Decode the file path
    const decodedPath = decodeURIComponent(req.params.filePath);
    
    // Construct the full path
    const fullPath = path.join('D:\\', decodedPath);

    // Log the full path
    console.log('Attempting to access file at:', fullPath);

    // Check if the file exists and has read permissions
    fs.access(fullPath, fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('File not found or access error:', err);
            res.status(404).json({ error: 'File not found' });
        } else {
            res.download(fullPath, (downloadErr) => {
                if (downloadErr) {
                    console.error('Error during file download:', downloadErr);
                    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error during file download' });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

i want could download from webview too like from browsers i try scoped storage i try with and without permission bu nothing. here will find how i try to download without success what you suggest?
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Request permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            }, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }

        // Initialize the WebView
        myWeb = findViewById(R.id.myWeb);
        myWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enable JavaScript
        myWeb.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); // Allow file access for uploads
        myWeb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // Enable DOM storage
        myWeb.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false); // Allow media playback without user gesture

        // Handle SSL errors
        myWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
            }

            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                if (url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".zip") || url.endsWith(".jpg") || url.endsWith(".png") ||
                        url.endsWith(".xlsx") || url.endsWith(".xls") || url.endsWith(".docx") || url.endsWith(".txt") || url.endsWith(".doc") || url.endsWith(".html"))  {
                    // Handle specific file types if needed
                    // For now, just return null to let WebView handle it
                    return null;
                }
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
            }
        });

        // Handle permission requests for the camera and other resources
        myWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
                Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        myWeb.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                startDownload(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype);
            }
        });

        // Enable WebView debugging
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

        // Load the desired URL
        myWeb.loadUrl("https://***.***.***.***:***/");
    }

    private void startDownload(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype) {
        // Create a DownloadManager request
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimetype);
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));

        // Enqueue the download
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;
            for (int result : grantResults) {
                if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    allPermissionsGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (allPermissionsGranted) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions granted. You can now download files.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions are required to download files.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (mFilePathCallback == null) return;
            Uri[] results = null;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    results = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data);
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        }
    }
}

